# User and pass from API

Tags: c#, smartsheet-api

**EDIT**
This question was for a workaround. Getting a successful login by using HttpWebRequests. Not on how to use the api.

**Question**
I noticed in the API there was no way to get a usernames password.

This is what I have now as a test. I thought I could just get the "Wrong user/pass" response first and go from there. All I get is the pages source code.

Anyone have any pointers or advice?

I am definitively logging in. In Account Admin and Login History, it shows me logging in. But the server is not serving any useful response text for the login. And now, I locked myself out using wrong passwords to sort through the streamreader lol.

```
public string DoVerification(string email, string password)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://app.smartsheet.com/b/home");

        var postData = "loginEmail=" + email;
        postData += "&loginPassword=" + password;
        postData += "&action=login";
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        return new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string response = DoVerification("test@test.com", "12345");
        MessageBox.Show(response.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to accomplish? Are you wanting to access the API? What are you expecting from the response? If you want to access the API, you cannot do that using the username and password - you have to use an access token, which you can generate in the account menu -> personal settings -> API Access.

Comment: Accomplish "I noticed in the API there was no way to get a usernames password." ie: Get the users password. I found another way by comparing the returned source from the a failed attempt and a successful attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comparing both sources from the returned response.

I have these two js functions.

Failed attempt

```
function loggedFailures() {
    logExternalGTMEvent({'event': 'app-login-failure','method': 'onsite','error': 'AUTH_NO_MATCHING_USER'}); return true
}
```

Successful attempt

```
function loggedFailures() {
    return false
}
```

I just simply check for one or the other.

And for the record, putting the users password in the api is not a bad idea.... Smartsheets lets us delete any user through the API, so I don't see what it would matter.

Comment: I beg to differ on the notion that putting the password in the API is ok, if by this you mean being able to retrieve the password of a user. If smartsheet were able to return the password from the API, that would mean they store the password in a format that is reversible, which is unacceptable by today's password standards. Passwords should be stored as the result of multiple passes of 1-way hashes with salt, which is what Smartsheet does. See https://www.smartsheet.com/security-info

Comment: It's application dependent. I would never bother salting a pass for something as simple as "accessing a spreadsheet". If I can delete, rewrite, add, and modify nearly any part of our smartsheet account through the api, then what the hell is the point of keeping the password so secure. If I were to be malicious, then I would just skip the password entirely, thanks the handy api token, bypassing any real reason to hide the password from the api in the first place.  But, these are our opinions.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you are trying to achieve or why you expect it to work.

There is no way to retrieve a password through the API. That would be a bad idea.

You aren't actually using the API. API endpoints start with `https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0` and are documented here: http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/

Comment: I am not here no.... obviously. Our application needed a way for our users to sign in using their smartsheet username and pass.